# How can I save a GUI window in Matlab(e.g. as png)?

Tags: matlab

I created a GUI inside Matlab;

To make it easy understandable let's say there is just a static and a non static textfield and also just one push button

In the nonstatic text field one can enter a number a and by pressing the push button we get an answer in the static text field, let's say just 2*a as an answer;

Now I want to have a screenshot of the GUI where there you can see the number a in the non static field and the result in the static text field;
So just how it is shown after pressing the button...

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: I would recommend having a look at [ScreenCapture](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-screencapture-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-figure-frame-or-component), submitted by Yair Altman to the FileExchange (meaning it is awesome)

Comment: Okay, but isnt there already a preinstalled possibility to get the snapshot of the gui window?

Comment: actually yes and it's quite easy; I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it's actually more simple than I thought and the`ScreenCapture` option might be overkill in your situation.

What you need is the [getframe](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) function, which captures the content of an axes or figure of your choice, here the GUI.

Here is the code for a simple example that you can copy and paste. Upon pressing the button, a new window appears with the content of the GUI. You can replace that part of the code with a call to `imwrite` to save the image in png format. The useful code is:

```
%// Capture content of current figure
F = getframe(gcf);
```

The image data is stored in the `cdata` property of the structure `F`, which you can save eg with.

```
%// imwrite(F.cdata,...)
```

So the whole code is the following:

```
function TestGUI
clc

hfigure  = figure('Position',[300 300 300 100],'Units','normalized','name','MyFigure');

handles.Edit1= uicontrol('Style','edit','String','','Position',[40 50 50 30]);
handles.Edit2= uicontrol('Style','edit','String','','Position',[100 50 50 30]);
handles.SnapShot= uicontrol('Style','push','String','Snapshot','Position',[160 50 70 30],'Callback',@(s,e) SnapShot_callback);

guidata(hfigure,handles);

%// Callback for button 1
    function SnapShot_callback
        handles = guidata(hfigure);

        %// Double entry from edit box 1. (do whatever you want)         
        x = str2double(get(handles.Edit1,'String'));

        NewX = 2*x;
        set(handles.Edit2,'String',NewX);

        %// Take the screenshot!
        F = getframe(gcf);

        figure()
        imshow(F.cdata); %// Image data is in F.cdata. You can replace by imwrite(F.cdata,...)

        %// Update handles structure.
        guidata(hfigure,handles);
    end
end
```

and a screenshot from my computer: on the left is the initial GUI and on the right is the new figure generated with the content of that GUI.

[image]

Comment: Okay let me try... :) But thank you already for your help..! :) I'll write if it worked.. :)

Comment: Hey... It works great thank you!! :) I'm really so thankful, you saved my day.. :)

Comment: that's awesome! In order to close the thread (and mean that you don't need more help for this topic) could you mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark beside it? Thanks and have fun!